# Updating values in an Array of Nested Objects in an Array of Nested Objects in an Array in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5757646866e59fac8d1d8589"),
  updatedAt: ISODate("2016-06-09T02:49:09.792Z"),
  createdAt: ISODate("2016-06-08T00:18:48.147Z"),
  books: [
    {
      name: "book1",
      id: "1",
      chapters: [
        {
          id: "1",
          name: "CH1",
          details: "Chapter 1",
          tables: [
            {
              table : 1, 
              heading : 'heading 1' // update this
            },
            {
              table: 2,
              heading: 'heading 2'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How to update table 1's heading programmatically.

This is a static way to do so:

```
db.books.update({_id: ObjectId("5757646866e59fac8d1d8589")},
{$set: {"books.0.chapters.0.tables.0.heading": "new Heading"}})
```

What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
db.books.update({_id: ObjectId("5757646866e59fac8d1d8589"), 
  'books.id': '1',
  'books.chapters.id':'1', 
  'books.chapters.tables.table':'1' }, 
{$set: {<what>}})
```

Comment: Maybe `db.books.update({_id: ObjectId("5757646866e59fac8d1d8589")}, {$set: {"books.0.chapters.0.tables.0.heading": "new Heading"}})`

Comment: You should clarify that how we supposed to select the *Table 1*? Is is just a positional update or based on some condition?

Comment: Just updated with what I am thinking of solution to be like.